# how to copy 'View Page Source' code into new file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When you right click here. you will find 'View Page Source' on clicking that, a new window opens with source code of that page.

My question is how would I copy those source code into new file either using javascript , jquery or using php.

Comment: You can use  `$('html').html()`  to get the source

Comment: If you want a copy of the source code of some page in a file on disk, that's client side so php is out of the picture. You can also press ctrl-s, select "Html only" and save the page's html source wherever you want.

Comment: you're confusing us all, http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/source_code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$.get( "http://www.example.com/", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Using PHP:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
print_r($homepage);
```

Reading from a URL and writing to a file:

```
file_put_contents('example_site.html', file_get_contents('http://www.example.com'));
```

***Note:*** Make sure you have write permissions in the directory where you are exporting this file to.

To display HTML data without browser rendering it:

```
$html= "<h1>Hello</h1>";
echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

Comment: but this will print on the screen. I want it to be copied on file like 'source.php'

Comment: @ Raja Amer Khan Your revised answer is actually copying the content of that file but not the source code of that page.

Comment: It does copy the source code (whatever the browser renders). I don't get what do you mean by source code? Try editing the saved file in your editor.

Comment: @ Raja Amer Khan source code means when you right click here you will able to find 'View Page Source' and when you click on that, a new window opens with all rendered code. i want all those codes to be copied in a new file. Actually I am fetching html code from database and on echoing html is getting rendered.

Comment: Your question is confusing me now. So you want to load your data from your database which contains your source code? But you want to print that source code as is in browser?

Comment: @ Raja Amer Khan yes you are right.

Comment: @rohitjaiswal Please check now. I've updated the answer.